# Vowel counter not working in Pure js

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a vowel counter in pure js but I cannot get the counters to work properly. and i cannot seem to find out where i am going wrong just need a little push or example to know how to fix this if that is ok. Can someone please help me thanks in advance.

This is my HTML:

```
<h1> Vowel Counter </h1>
Please enter text for your vowel count:
<br>
<textarea id="text" rows="10" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="countVowels();">Count Vowels</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
function countVowels() {

    var text = document.getElementById("text").value;

    var arrayOfLetters = text.split("");
    var arrayOfVowels = ("AEIOU");

    // Set up our counters
    var countA = 0;
    var countE = 0;
    var countI = 0;
    var countO = 0;
    var countU = 0;

    // Output the results:
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Total Letters: " + arrayOfLetters.length + "<br />";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "A's: " + arrayOfVowels.length + countA + "<br />";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "E's: " + arrayOfVowels.length +countE + "<br />";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "I's: " + arrayOfVowels.length +countI + "<br />";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "O's: " + arrayOfVowels.length +countO + "<br />";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "U's: " + arrayOfVowels.length +countU + "<br />";
}
```

And a have attached my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Matt1990/3Ckw2/43/

Comment: you forgot to count the vowels. that step between setup and output.

Comment: so all i need to do is put ++ is that all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using regular expressions instead of loops and so many if conditions. The complexity and maintainability of the code is bad in the above solutions unless you consider regex as not being pure js.

```
 var countA = text.match(/[Aa]/g).length;
```

This will give you direct count. For finding maxval, use basic sort algorithms to find the max and then assign a css style class to it. That is not a technical problem to solve.

Comment: how do i do that though i have never done any sort algorithms before

Comment: Refer to bigocheatsheet.com and pick one from the sorting table. In your case bubble sort should yield the max value faster. You just have to put the values into an array first.

Comment: Is there a different way to do it just to add some more code to get the most used vowel to be bold i have got everything else to work other than to get the most used vowel to come up bold. thanks if you can help me. @sbjumani

Comment: There are multiple threads on 'highlight text CSS'. Please refer to one of them. Happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

How are you counting the vowels?
Right now it is showing 50 for each vowel count because arrayOfVowels.length = 5 and countA (for example), is simply 0. You aren't adding any numbers together, but you're adding 5 to the string 0 which results in "50".

Comment: thats why i asked the question i want to find out how many vowels are in what ever a person enter into the box but i dont know where i have gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

You simply have no mechanism to count vowels, it's not that your "vowel counter" doesn't work. You set up everything correctly but fail to work through the text and systematically count the vowels. You can improve this code by automatically making the letters lower or upper case, so you don't have to use the or operator to check for both cases. I could've done that fast but I am just too lazy...

This vowel counter will work:

```
function countVowels() {

var text = document.getElementById("text").value;

var arrayOfLetters = text.split("");
var arrayOfVowels = ("AEIOU");

// Set up our counters
var countA = 0;
var countE = 0;
var countI = 0;
var countO = 0;
var countU = 0;

for(i=0; i < arrayOfLetters.length; i++) {
    if (arrayOfLetters[i] == "A" || arrayOfLetters[i] == "a") {
        countA ++;
    }
    if (arrayOfLetters[i] == "E" || arrayOfLetters[i] == "e") {
        countE ++;
    }
    if (arrayOfLetters[i] == "I" || arrayOfLetters[i] == "i") {
        countI ++;
    }
    if (arrayOfLetters[i] == "O" || arrayOfLetters[i] == "o") {
        countO ++;
    }
    if (arrayOfLetters[i] == "U" || arrayOfLetters[i] == "u") {
        countU ++;
    }
}

// Output the results:
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "Total Letters: " + arrayOfLetters.length + "<br />";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "A's: " + countA + "<br />";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "E's: " + countE + "<br />";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "I's: " + countI + "<br />";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "O's: " + countO + "<br />";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "U's: " + countU + "<br />";
```

}

Comment: Ok thanks that works now thanks so much and what would i have to add to make the most used vowel bold.